# getParcelableExtra returns in NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open DetailActivity from Mainactivity using an intent which puts a class object that implements Parcelable as an extra. I did check that the object has the correct data before calling putExtra. The stack is pointing to call to readList.

MainActivity.java

```
    movieViewAdapter =  new MovieViewAdapter(new ArrayList<Movies>(), new MovieViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Movies movie) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("thisMovie",movie);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

This will open DetailsActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        // Line 52
        Movies movie =  (Movies) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("thisMovie");
        .....
        .....           
    }
```

I get following Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:3177)
at android.os.Parcel.readList(Parcel.java:2178)
at com.example.android.popularmoviesstage1.Models.Movies$1.createFromParcel(Movies.java:73)
at com.example.android.popularmoviesstage1.Models.Movies$1.createFromParcel(Movies.java:56)
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2851)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2745)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3114)
at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:273)
at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:226)
at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:939)
at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:7167)
at com.example.android.popularmoviesstage1.Activities.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:52)
```

Here is my implementation of Movies.java

```
public final static Parcelable.Creator<Movies> CREATOR = new Creator<Movies>() {
        @SuppressWarnings({
                "unchecked"
        })
        public Movies createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            Movies instance = new Movies();
            ....
            ....
            //Line 73
            in.readList(instance.genreIds, (java.lang.Integer.class.getClassLoader()));
            ....
            ....
            return instance;
        }
        public Movies[] newArray(int size) {
            return (new Movies[size]);
        }
};
```

Comment: `instance.genreIds` is null.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you! You are right. genreIds is null. But before I call putExtra, I see   genreIds=[18, 10749].  Any idea why would it be null?

Comment: If I correctly understand what you're saying, that's the `movie` instance in `MainActivity` that you're sending on the `Intent`. The Exception is happening in `DetailsActivity`, when it tries to create a new instance from the passed `Parcel`.

Comment: Yes, Sorry if my questions was not clear. I am an Android Newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You shuld use Parcelable's plugin to generate the POJO. Works prefectly for me.
That plugin is avaible in Android Studio plugins repository.